# C - unknown type name (global struct)

Tags: c, types, struct, global

I have a file a.h which defines the structure:

```
typedef struct q_elem_s
{
    def_task task;
    struct q_elem_s *next;
} q_elem;
```

def_task is a structure in a second file b.h.

```
typedef struct task_s
{
    int id;
    int length;
} def_task;
```

Now my compiler says that def_task task inside q_elem_s is unknown?

a.c includes b.h. What is the problem then?

Comment: a.h should include b.h

Comment: Strange, I have another version of this code and it worked without this. But that helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> > a.h should include b.h
>
> Strange, I have another version of this code and it worked without
>   this.

When it worked without `a.h` including `b.h`, it probably did because `a.c` (or whatever main file) included `b.h` before `a.h`.